# Como fazer deploy de uma aplicação em NodeJS local?

Tags: node.js, deploy

Fala pessoal , tudo bem ? 
Andei pesquisando na web mas fiquei confuso , sou novo na programação em node fiz uma aplicação mas não sei como fazer o deploy local como um serviço por exemplo. Por onde posso começar ? é possível fazer isso ?

Agradeço pela ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo usar o `pm2` para rodar o servidor como um tipo de serviço. É bem simples de usar.

`npm install pm2@latest -g`

Para usar se estiver na raiz do projeto, onde se encontra o `index.js`, `mains.js` ou `server.js`:

`pm2 start index.js`

Para parar é `pm2 stop index` ou `pm2 stop <nome da instancia>`

Após o start ele libera o console aí é só monitorar o status `pm2 status`

Os logs `pm2 logs` e para mais informações `pm2 show <nome da instancia>`
ou `pm2 show index`.

Geralmente eu carrego um `script.json` contendo várias informações como as variáveis de ambiente, nome da instancia, etc. Também há alguns comandos para salvar a instancia do pm2 e toda vez que o computador ou servidor iniciar/reinicializar ele starta novamente. Na documentação dele explica tudo certinho.

> Referência: [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)